# Finding eigenvalues of a system of ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to find the eigenvalues and eigenfunctions of $y''(t) + \lambda y(t) = 0$, $0 \leq t \leq 1$, $y'(0) + y(0) = 0$ and $y(1) = 0$.

I am confused on how one find the eigenvalues of this.

First, I change the equation into a system of first order ode's. 
Let $x_{1} = y(t)$ and $x_{2} = y'(t)$

$\left [\begin{matrix} \frac{d}{dt} & 0 \\ 0 & \frac{d}{dt}\end{matrix} \right ] \cdot \left [\begin{matrix}x_{1} \\ x_{2} \end{matrix} \right ]= \left [  \begin{matrix}0 & 1 \\ -\lambda & 0 \end{matrix}\right ] \cdot \left [ \begin{matrix} x_{1} \\ x_{2} \end{matrix} \right ]$

Then

$$\left ( \left [ \begin{matrix} \frac{d}{dt} & 0 \\ 0 & \frac{d}{dt}\end{matrix} \right ] -  \left [  \begin{matrix}0 & 1 \\ -\lambda & 0 \end{matrix}\right ]\right )\cdot \left [ \begin{matrix} x_{1} \\ x_{2} \end{matrix} \right ] = 0$$

So $\left [  \begin{matrix} \frac{d}{dt} & 0 \\ \lambda & \frac{d}{dt}\end{matrix} \right ] \cdot \left [ \begin{matrix} x_{1} \\ x_{2}\end{matrix} \right ]$.

Then taking the det of the matrix, $\frac{d^2}{dt^2} - \lambda \cdot (0 ) = 0$.

I think i've done something wrong because what I've written, $\frac{d^2}{dt^2} - \lambda \cdot (0 ) = 0$, doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

First consider the initial values $y(0) = 0, \; y'(1) = 0$. After you are able to do this problem, using your initial values won't be as difficult.

You wish to find the eigenvalues and eigenfunctions of $y''(t) + \lambda y(t) = 0$ such that $0 \leq t \leq 1$ and $y(0) = 0, \; y'(1) =0 $.

Let $x_{1}(t) = y(t)$ and $x_{2}(t) = y'(t)$. Then the initial values become $x_{1}(0) = 0$ and $x_{2}(1) = 0$.

Let $\mathbf{X} = \left (  \begin{matrix}x_{1}(t) \\ x_{2}(t) \end{matrix}\right )$. We now have the following first order system $$\mathbf{X}' = \left ( \begin{matrix}0 & 1\\ -\lambda & 0 \end{matrix}\right ) \mathbf{X}$$
Where $\mathbf{A} = \left ( \begin{matrix}0 & 1\\ -\lambda & 0 \end{matrix}\right )$ is the coefficient matrix.

I find the general solution to be $\mathbf{X} = c_{1}\left ( \begin{matrix}1 \\ i\sqrt[]{\lambda} \end{matrix} \right ) e^{i\sqrt[]{\lambda}t} + c_{2} \left ( \begin{matrix}1 \\ -i\sqrt[]{\lambda} \end{matrix} \right )e^{-i\sqrt[]{\lambda}t}$.

Now we examine $\mathbf{X}$ for which values of $\lambda$ allow for a non-trivial solution. We split $\lambda$ into three cases. Namely, $\lambda < 0, \; \lambda =0, \; \lambda > 0$. Note that any real number possesses a square root. Therefore, for the first case, $\lambda < 0$, let $\lambda = -k^2$ for $k \in \mathbb{R}$. Then we obtain $$\mathbf{X} = c_{1} \left ( \begin{matrix}1 \\ -k \end{matrix} \right )e^{-k t} + c_{2} \left ( \begin{matrix}1 \\ k \end{matrix} \right )e^{k t}$$ By the first initial value condition $x(0)=0$, we have $$c_{1} + c_{2} = 0 \implies c_{1} = -c_{2}$$ Now by the second initial value condition we have $$-c_{1} k e^{-k} + c_{2}ke^{k} = 0$$ Then $c_{2} k \left ( e^{-k}+e^{k} \right ) = 0$. Note that $e^{-k} + e^{k} = 2 \cosh(k)$. Either $c_{2}k = 0$ or $2\cosh(k) = 0$. Since $2\cosh(k) = 0$ for nonreal $k$, then $c_{2}k = 0$ and since $k \neq 0$ then $c_{2} = 0 \implies c_{1} = 0$.

Hence, for $\lambda < 0$, $\mathbf{X}$ is trivial.

Now continue this process for $\lambda = 0$ and $\lambda > 0$ until you find $X$  to be nontrivial. Then you can examine the corresponding eigenvalue and eigenfunction to that $\lambda$

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to write down an explicit solution to the ode that verifies e.g. $y(1)=0$ and then seek for a condition on $\lambda$ that will satisfy the condition at $0$.